# Why installing pySerial from tar.gz doesn't work in Windows?

Tags: python, module, pip, package, pyserial

trying to install pySerial on Windows 10 by downloading the serial-0.0.97.tar.gz and using

`pip install serial-0.0.97.tar.gz`

but this gives

```
Processing c:\users\johndoe\downloads\python\serial-0.0.97.tar.gz
Collecting future>=0.17.1 (from serial==0.0.97)
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001CA15D5C190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')': /simple/future/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001CA15D5C370>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')': /simple/future/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001CA15D5CD90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')': /simple/future/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001CA15D5CDC0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')': /simple/future/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001CA15D5CAC0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')': /simple/future/
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement future>=0.17.1 (from serial==0.0.97) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for future>=0.17.1 (from serial==0.0.97)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it still trying to reach the Pypi repository?

P.S.

just in case:

```
Python 3.8.3rc1
```

&

```
pip 19.2.3 from c:\users\johndoe\python\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
```

Comment: this is not a package or windows specific error, but related to your network. Are oyu behind a firewall or something?

Comment: You're right, it was a Firewall issue. IT made an exception for pip, it works now.

Comment: though it works now, I fail to understand why the network connection is necessary. Doesn't the tar contain all the necessary files for install?

Comment: No, it contains all the source code of `serial`, but not its dependencies (in this case `future``), which are then downloaded on the fly if they are not available anymore